# Generate coverage report from linux command line

Tags: java, linux, code-coverage

I am trying to generate a code coverage for a jar using emma.
I`ve got emma.jar from http://sourceforge.net/projects/emma/files/emma-release/2.0.5312/emma-2.0.5312-lib.zip/download and I copied myJar.jar in my workspace directory.
myJar its a jar for which i want to find out code" coverage.
 I tried the following commands:

```
~/workspace$ java emmarun -cp .:emma:myJar -jar myJar.jar 
~/workspace$ java emmarun -cp ./emma.jar -jar myJar.jar
~/workspace$ java emma run -cp emma.jar -jar myJar.jar
~/workspace$ java emmarun -cp .:emma.jar:myJar.jar -jar myJar.jar
```

but every time a `Error: Could not find or load main class emmarun erro is raised Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun your_code_dir
```

Comment: What do you mean by your_code_dir? I can put there myJar.jar? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I meant _your_java_jar_ file to check according to the parameters on [link](http://emma.sourceforge.net/intro.html)

Comment: java -cp emma.jar emmarun -jar  myJar.jar [EMMA v2.0, build 5312]
emmarun: failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from [/home/luci/workspace/myJar.jar]

Comment: You have to consider that a code coverage tool only works against your source code. Have a look on the emma's command-line help: `-classpath <list of directories and zip/jar files>
                load/coverage classpath
  -jar          run an executable jar file 
  -sp, -sourcepath <list of source directories>
                Java source path for generating reports
... `